# Missing Search in Properties in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have opened VS2022 (V17.0.4)  two times at the moment.

In a **VB Windows Forms .net Framework** project I can search in a control's property:
[image]

In a **C# Windows Form .NET6** Project (Core) I cannot (there is no textbox for searching a property like in the first screenshot):

[image]

Is this search functionality indeed only availabvle in the .net Framework project or does it depend on VB or is this a setting I can set to "On" somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out that this search feature is not provided by VisualStudio, but by the DevExpress extension.